# How to resolve a Maven "The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact" error?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-war-plugin, maven-install-plugin

I’m using Maven 3.2.3.  I used to be able to run “mvn clean install” on my WAR project and the WAR would get installed to my local repository.  However, I recently added a configuration so that my WAR would be constructed in place (config is below).  Now, when I run

```
mvn clean install
```

I get the error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (install) on project myproject: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact -> [Help 1]
```

How do I fix this?  I tried making the “install” goal of the maven-install-plugin the default, but that didn’t help.  Below is my Maven configuration …

```
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</directory>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <useCache>true</useCache>
                        <workDirectory>/tmp/${project.artifactId}/war/work</workDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-war</id>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>war-inplace</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>inplace</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-install</id>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: I think that, as you specify  `<id>default-war</id><phase>none</phase>`, no artifact is generated. So nothing can be installed.

Comment: That is indeed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Tome is correct. I was building a jar and I had chosen to skip if it is empty. While building skeleton, there were no classes and it failed with that error. Changed false to make it work

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Automatic-Module-ame>com.test.acceptance.project</Automatic-Module-Name>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score -2):

Adding the below rpm entry

```
    %_rpmfilename noarch/%%{NAME}-%%{VERSION}-%%{RELEASE}.noarch.rpm
```

in each of the following files mentioned here solved the problem for me. (from 64 to no-arch).

```
    vim /etc/rpm/macros
    vim ~/.rpmmacros
```